# Unable to get custom parameters passed using Twilio connect function for outgoing and incoming calls

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

Am trying to create a call center with Twilio, am almost there but now am stuck because i can't get custom passed parameters.

My main aim is to allow customers to call but first they should provide their emails and names first, then click call-customer button, i want to receive the custom parameters on the agent's side.

Now i try to pass the parameters but i can't retrieve them.

Here is my code to make and receive calls and to pass and get the parameters

(Customer side)This code allows outgoing calls, customers to make calls to the call-center agents

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Twilio\Jwt\ClientToken;

$accountSid = '';
$authToken  = '';
$appSid = '';

$capability = new ClientToken($accountSid, $authToken);
$capability->allowClientOutgoing($appSid);
$token = $capability->generateToken();
```

So according to the documentation i should pass the custom parameters like this:

```
var params = {"name": "John", "email": "john@gmail.com"};
             Twilio.Device.connect(params);
```

(Agent side) This code allows incoming calls from customers to agents.

```
$accountSid = '';
$authToken  = '';

$capability = new ClientToken($accountSid, $authToken);
$capability->allowClientIncoming('joey');
$token = $capability->generateToken();
```

In the agent side i use this code to receive customer information or custom parameters. 
According to the documentation a code to get custom parameters is this:

```
if (connection.customParameters.hasOwnProperty("name")) {
            let displayName = connection.customParameters.get("name");
            console.log(displayName)
        }

        if (connection.customParameters.hasOwnProperty("email")) {
            let customerID = connection.customParameters.get("email");
            console.log(customerID)
        }
```

but i get undefined

So when a customer calls this twilio function en-queues the call and assign it to an operator

here is the code:

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();

    twiml.say(" Please hold, while we connect you to one of our available agent ");
    twiml.enqueue({
    workflowSid: context.WORKFLOW_SID
    }).task({}, `{"selected_skill":"operator"}`);
  callback(null, twiml);
};
```

Then from here an available operator will accept the task then dial an agent

The operator dials the client like this

```
{"skills":["operator"],"contact_uri":"client:joey"}
```

Please help
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my take on the associated documentation, it looks like the parameters are only sent to the Twilio client via TwiML, as shown here.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript/changelog#160-aug-29-2018

> Added support for custom incoming parameters from TwiML as Map Connection.customParameters. When a TwiML application sends
>   custom parameters using the  noun, these parameters will be
>   added to Connection.customParameters

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Dial>
    <Client>
      <Identity>alice</Identity>
      <Parameter name="foo" value="bar"/>
      <Parameter name="baz" value="123"/>
    </Client>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

It sounds like you are using the Task Router JavaScript SDK, maybe you can add these parameters as attributes to the [task](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/enqueue#attributes-workflowSid), and then access those tasks from the [Task Router client SDK](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/js-sdk/workspace/worker#reservation-created)?

Comment: Thanks @Alan. i see this twiml but i don't understand it. like how do i pass  data from html inputs to this twiml , because before a customer make a call they have to input their email and name then click to call, on the agent side they answer the call and they see the products that the customer bought (something like crm)

Comment: @tp45, you're using the TwiML `<Enqueue>` verb to pass the call to Task Router, so I am pretty sure you cannot use the TwiML `<Parameter>` noun to pass information to the agent.

For the customer leg, you should see the params you pass to your Twilio Function under, `event.name` and `event.email`, so you can use those values to add Task Router attributes to pass into the Task Router Client via `<Enqueue>` and pull them out that way.

So, edit your Twilio Function to change this:
`.task(`{"selected_skill":"operator", "name": "${event.name}", "email": "${event.email}"`);`

Comment: So i can still set the custom parameters like this ```let connection = Twilio.Device.connect({
  "customerID": "375d1d60-083b-404d", 
  "selectedProductID": "87144192-73e2-45a6"
});```  then get them like  this ```if (connection.customParameters.hasOwnProperty("selectedProductID")) {
   let selectedProductID = connection.customParameters.get("selectedProductID");
   // Do something with selectedProductID 
}```

Comment: Yes to first one, no to second.

Comment: Thank you so much @Alan everything works i can get the custom parameters. am getting them like this: ```reservation.task.attributes.name```

Comment: Outstanding :) Thanks for sharing and glad I could help.